# Pandas assigning random string to each group as new column

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, pandas-groupby

We have a dataframe like

```
Out[90]: 
   customer_id                 created_at
0     11492288 2017-03-15 10:20:18.280437
1      8953727 2017-03-16 12:51:00.145629
2     11492288 2017-03-15 10:20:18.284974
3     11473213 2017-03-09 14:15:22.712369
4      9526296 2017-03-14 18:56:04.665410
5      9526296 2017-03-14 18:56:04.662082
```

I would like to create new column here, based on groups of customer_id, random strings of 8 characters assigned to each group.

For example the output would then look like

```
Out[90]: 
   customer_id                 created_at     code
0     11492288 2017-03-15 10:20:18.280437 nKAILfyV
1      8953727 2017-03-16 12:51:00.145629 785Vsw0b
2     11492288 2017-03-15 10:20:18.284974 nKAILfyV
3     11473213 2017-03-09 14:15:22.712369 dk6JXq3u
4      9526296 2017-03-14 18:56:04.665410 1WESdAsD
5      9526296 2017-03-14 18:56:04.662082 1WESdAsD
```

I am used to R and dplyr, and it is super easy to write this transformation using them. I am looking for something similar in Pandas to this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

df %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(code = stri_rand_strings(1, 8))
```

I can figure out the random character part. Just curious on how Pandas groupby works in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pandas (R's `mutate`) is `transform`

```
df['code']=df.groupby('customer_id').transform(lambda x:pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,1))
df
Out[314]: 
   customer_id  created_at      code
0     11492288  2017-03-15  L6Odf65d
1      8953727  2017-03-16  fwLpgLnt
2     11492288  2017-03-15  L6Odf65d
3     11473213  2017-03-09  AuSUPnJ9
4      9526296  2017-03-14  U1AiLyx0
5      9526296  2017-03-14  U1AiLyx0
```

EDIT (from cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ) :`df.groupby('customer_id').customer_id.transform(lambda x:pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,1))`

Also some improvement in you R code ,

```
Match=data.frame(A=unique(df$customer_id),B=replicate(length(unique(df$year)), stri_rand_strings(1, 8)))
df$Code=Match$B[match(df$customer_id,Match$A)]
```

Comment: Wow... Nice one! Learned something new.

Comment: `pd.util.testing.rands_array`... nice!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Though when I do this the assignment is failing?
`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15, placement implies 1`

Comment: The actual dataframe has 16 columns btw

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you ~ :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am setting up my password by using this method :)

Comment: @Wen I know it works based on the sample data but the actual dataframe has 16 columns. Therefore the RHS of your equation is creating 15 columns of random strings.

Comment: @user4505419 Try: `df.groupby('customer_id').customer_id.transform(lambda x:pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,1))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ here you go:)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you guys might appreciate my derivative work.

Comment: @Wen I learned something today!  That's worth more than upvotes (-:

Answer (score 7):

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters, digits
chars = list(ascii_letters + digits)

choose = lambda x, k=8: ''.join(random.choices(chars, k=k))
df.assign(code=df.groupby('customer_id').transform(choose))

   customer_id                  created_at      code
0     11492288  2017-03-15 10:20:18.280437  S5HtmbeN
1      8953727  2017-03-16 12:51:00.145629  MMfFFn8U
2     11492288  2017-03-15 10:20:18.284974  S5HtmbeN
3     11473213  2017-03-09 14:15:22.712369  4VsKmDZ5
4      9526296  2017-03-14 18:56:04.665410  VhQfu2Rf
5      9526296  2017-03-14 18:56:04.662082  VhQfu2Rf
```

---

Inspired by @Wen's use of `pd.util.testing.rands_array`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.customer_id.values)

df.assign(code=pd.util.testing.rands_array(8, u.size)[f])

   customer_id                  created_at      code
0     11492288  2017-03-15 10:20:18.280437  tSuQbTBm
1      8953727  2017-03-16 12:51:00.145629  qmCl6NEX
2     11492288  2017-03-15 10:20:18.284974  tSuQbTBm
3     11473213  2017-03-09 14:15:22.712369  Wsa3lNxh
4      9526296  2017-03-14 18:56:04.665410  jBfXS2Nk
5      9526296  2017-03-14 18:56:04.662082  jBfXS2Nk
```

Comment: Cool! You got rid of the groupby. I'd be interested in seeing how well this does on a large dataframe. I'll wager a guess it's faster.

Comment: @piRSquared Guys I accepted the other one as the correct answer already but this literally performs like 1000x faster then the groupby method,

Comment: Two things... 1) You can always change your accepted answer and I'd advocate that you always accept with your conscience. 2) I'm completely ok with you choosing @Wen's answer.  If we both contributed to your final solution, I'd throw my vote towards his answer given that I was inspired by it anyway.